# Convert from hex string (from UCS-2) into UTF-8

Tags: c#, encoding, hex

I'm using a third party SMS provider and have hit an issue with converting from UCS-2 messages back into readable text.

Their API documentation has this code sample which converts UCS-2 messges into what I'm picking up on the API.

```
string message = "Это тестовое сообщение юникода";
byte[] ba = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes (message);
var hexString = BitConverter.ToString (ba);
Console.WriteLine ("@U" + hexString.Replace("-",""));
```

Which converts the `message` string into

```
@U042D0442043E00200442043504410442043E0432043E043500200441043E043E043104490435043D043804350020044E043D0438043A043E04340430
```

This looks like the UCS-2 messages I'm picking up from their API.
Unfortunately they don't give any code samples of how to convert the messages back into a readable form.

I'm sure its not there in the docs because its something simple - but I just seem to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reverse what you have (the string of hex prefixed with `@U`)

```
var message = "Это тестовое сообщение юникода";
var ba = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(message);
var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
var encoded = "@U" + hexString.Replace("-", "");
Console.WriteLine(encoded);

// reverse
var bytes = Enumerable.Range(2, encoded.Length-2)
   .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
   .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(encoded.Substring(x, 2), 16))
   .ToArray();

var result = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
@U042D0442043E00200442043504410442043E0432043E043500200441043E043E043104490435043D043804350020044E043D0438043A043E04340430
Это тестовое сообщение юникода
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wq6cie)

Answer (score 1):

looks like this would be the reverse:

```
string message = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(ba);
```

The extraction of bytes could be done by such a method:

```
private IEnumerable<byte> GetTheBytes(string uc2Message)
{
    string bytesOnly = uc2Message.Trim('@', 'U');
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesOnly.Length-2; i+=2)
    {
        yield return Convert.ToByte($"{bytesOnly[i]}{bytesOnly[i+1]}", 16);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(GetTheBytes(uc2Message).ToArray()));
```